# Inclusion $\mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ induces an injection in scalar extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

#### Question

Given a torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (aka. abelian group) $G$, let $i: \mathbb{Q} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the inclusion. I want to show that
$$
i \otimes \mathrm{id}: \mathbb{Q} \mathbin{\otimes_\mathbb{Z}} G \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \mathbin{\otimes_\mathbb{Z}} G
$$
is injective.

I feel it should really work because $\mathbb{R}$ is "sufficiently independent" of $\mathbb{Q}$, but I haven't been able to show it.

#### Context

I'm trying to embed $G$ into a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space. I already arrived at $\mathbb{Q} \mathbin{\otimes_\mathbb{Z}} G$ by the proof of theorem 4.26.2 in [this](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf) note by Keith Conrad, but it does not generalize to $\mathbb{R}$.
Also, all spaces are in fact partially ordered in my case, but I noticed that most proofs can be extended to support the ordering.

Comment: $G$ is torsion-free, hence flat.

Comment: @MooS That should be an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torsion-free modules over Dedekind domains are flat, in particular torsion-free abelian groups are flat.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to see with that. Quite simply, a torsion-free $\mathbf Z$-module is flat, as is any torsion-free $A$-module over  a PID or more generally over a Dedekind ring.